# error: 'CERT_STORE_PROV_MEMORY' was not declared in this scope

Tags: x509certificate

I'm a windows XP newbe, I'm trying to learn how to write some C, C++ to manipulate certificates and use IPsec.

I have no XP SDKs, so I grabbed mingsys and mingw to access gcc, g++.

Can anyone tell me where the heck CERT_... stuff is declared?  I assumed it would be a ".h" file, or something accessed by a #include.

Mike

Answer (score 1):

If you had the sdk, it would probably be wincrypt.h according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376559(VS.85).aspx. If you want to use those methods, your probably need to have the SDK (not so sure about that though).

In any case, grep/findstr is your friend.